# LibGdx Background not Rendering

Tags: java, libgdx, screen, rendering

I'm using multiple screens for my LibGdx Java game and I'm having trouble getting the start screen and the death screen rendering the background. The background is in the right place, as I have checked. The Main.java (The game itself) works but nothing else. The only thing that works on the start and death screen is the inputs such as keyboard input.

Code:
FishGame.java

```
package us.webco.fish;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class FishGame extends Game {
public SpriteBatch batch;

public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    this.setScreen(new StartScreen(this));
}

public void render() {
    super.render();
}

public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
}
```

}

StartScreen.java (Empty functions cut out)

```
package us.webco.fish;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;

public class StartScreen implements Screen{
private Texture backgroundImage;
private Sprite backgroundToSprite;
final FishGame game;

public StartScreen(final FishGame gam) {
    game = gam;
    backgroundImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("../android/assets/startScreen.jpg"));
    backgroundToSprite = new Sprite(backgroundImage);
    backgroundToSprite.setSize(Main.width, Main.height);
}

@Override
public void render(float p) {
    p = 1/60f; /* FPS */
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f,0.4f,0.7f,1.0f); /* Setting a default background color */
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); /* Rendering purposes */

    game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(backgroundToSprite, Main.width, Main.height);
    game.batch.end();

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.X)) {
        System.out.println("Start Game");
        game.setScreen(new Main(game));
        dispose();
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.Z)) {
        System.out.println("Game has been quit!");
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }

}
```

Main.java uses game.batch, too. I'm not sure why it's not working as I followed the LibGdx tutorial, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
backgroundImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("startScreen.jpg"));
```

EDIT: spriteBatch.draw(..., position.x, position.y);

Your use width and height for the position, you are not out of the screen

Comment: Thank you, this sorted it! I can't believe I actually did that, haha!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your camera position right?

Do you update camera and set projection matrix to your SpriteBatch?

Comment: I've not had to use a camera before, should I be using one?

Comment: You will definitely need to use camera at some point (would be much easier).

I guess your problem is with screen offset as user below mentioned.

You can find very detailed tutorial for orthographic camera (that is the one that you need) here. If you encounter any trouble implementing/understanding feel free to ask anything, i will help you.